# Substitute Key on 128 Bit Encryption

Tags: encryption

I'm trying to obtain a copy of program that uses 128 bit encryption,  I've been denied since it could decrypt ANYTHING that anyone else has saved in it.

I suggested giving me the program, but on mine just change the key so it only works on my copy and no others.

I know little of encryption, but it sounds like a logical solution to me.  I get the program, and they get to keep their key secret.

My program with a different key would not read their files.

Is this correct?

Comment: This program encrypts/decrypts anything you feed it, always using the same key?

Answer (score 1):

There are a great number of assumptions to be made because you do not give a lot of details. But, yes, if you change the keys it uses, then it encrypts/decrypts it's own unique set.